# HTML Button with a picture - does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the page after clicking on my button.

I tried this out:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='stackedbar.html';" class="btn btn-light btn-lg material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="button" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Stacked bar chart">
                    <img src="barchart_schwarzweiss.png" width="38" height="45" border="0" alt=""> </input>
```

It works but the picture is not in the button. Could someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<button>` instead of `<input>` as the latter has not to be closed.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='stackedbar.html';" class="btn btn-light btn-lg material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="button" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Stacked bar chart">
<img src="barchart_schwarzweiss.png" width="38" height="45" border="0" alt="" /> </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code. The `button` tag does not have a closing tag, but there is a `submit` closing tag. Change the closing submit tag to a closing button tag

Comment: Thanks :) I've edited it. Now I have the problem that my picture is not in the button